# How can i write decorations for User and other Models in django?

Tags: python, django

i have a question about writing decorations in django. i have table `Token` below, when user click to **logged_in with token**, i want to redirect to home and `is_logged_in` field became `True`. But when User doesn't choose any `Token`, i want to redirect to `list-tokens` for people choose token to login that they want. So how can i write decorations when people not yet choose any Token and redirect people to `token-lists`. Thanks

This is my `Token` model:

```py
class Token(models.Model):
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomeUser, related_name='tokens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_logged_in = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.access_token
```

Comment: Can you share your `token-lists` view?

Comment: @AmanGarg token-lists is a list of multiple token User can choose to logged in with and after choose one i want to redirect people to home page, if people not choose one, i want to redirect to 'list-tokens' for people to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use default [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator for this. This is assuming `CustomeUser` is default `User` model.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def token_check(user):
    return user.tokens.filter(is_logged_in=True).exists()

@user_passes_test(token_check, login_url='list-token')
def my_view(request):
    # ...
```

You might want to consider using middlewares for this as well.

Comment: User have multiple token, they choose each of them, if token has choose, is_logged_in = True then  redirect to home page dashboard, if not will redirect to 'list-tokens'. I think you misapprehension my idea.

Comment: This decorator will redirect users to `list-token` if they have no token attached. It will work if user has multiple tokens. Do you want to additionally check that those tokens have `is_logged_in = True`? Anyway provide `token-lists` view, where you attach tokens to users.

Comment: Can i check for one of multiple token have field is_logged_in = True? Thanks

Comment: @MinhTuan updated answer. It will not redirect user to `list-token` if he has at least one token with `is_logged_in = True`.